# Is it possible to trace Xcode C++ compile dependencies?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'd like to identify all the include files of a particular file that I chose as a starting point in a C++ project, and then all the include files of those include files and so on until I have everything that I require to compile the file I chose as my starting point.

The background: I am trying to take a file from the 'middle' of a project and 'lift out' just it and all its dependencies. I can do this dependency checking manually but can't see any obvious way to do it automatically in the Xcode IDE.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any support in Xcode itself for doing this. However, it's not too difficult to do yourself, especially if it's only one file you're interested in.

You can add the `-E` flag to `g++` to have it stop after preprocessing your source file. The preprocessed source file will have comments mentioning all the `#include`d files. Those lines can be extracted with a simple invocation of `grep`.

Xcode can tell you the full list of arguments it passes to `g++` when compiling your files if you go to `Build > Build Results`, start a build, and click the while oval with lines at the far right of the line saying "Compile somefile.cpp..."

The [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) tool has the ability to render graphs of `#include`s from both source and header files. It's nice, but probably a bit heavyweight for what you're looking to do.

Comment: The version of xcode I have does not actually have the 'white ovals' you mention, but I noticed that there is a 'preprocess' command when you right click a something.cpp file. This produces all the preprocessor output and puts it into the editor window. It seems however that not every file that is 'included' actually has the word 'include' in the output, but I think using the indication that a new file has started (1 at the end of the line) will get the same information (it *appeared* to work for me...): somePreprocessorOutput.txt | grep '" 1'

Answer (score 0):

What compiler do you use? If it is MSVC++, then look at usage of options: /P, /EP /P
When you use g++, then try cpp utility.

Both ways allows you build file with all includes (name of included files would be included as comments)